# Accesing variable declared without a name (just new keyword)

Tags: c#

I have  a DataSet named dS in which i want to load XML.

So i would use the function `dS.ReadXml();`

The paramter for `ReadXml` function is `XmlTextReader` Object.

If i pass object as

```
ds.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\MyDataSource.xml"));
```

the dataset would be loaded. But later on, i want to close that `XmlTextReader` object. Although i didn't declared it with a name like

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(somepath);
```

How can i close the reader???

Comment: you have answered yourself already: with a variable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a variable, otherwise you can't access it.

And while you are at it, use the `using` statement:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "MyDataSource.xml"));
using (var reader = new XmlTextTreader(path))
{
  ds.ReadXml(reader);
}
```

The `using` statement automatically calls `Dispose` on `reader` when exiting the scope of the `using` statement.

Note: You should use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) instead of concatting the path yourself. Saves you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The **XmlTextReader** object is used  by the **DataSet** object, which is why it isn't garbage-collected.

Now if you think of it, it means that the **DataSet** object controls the *XmlTextReader** object.

So the best way is to call:

```
ds.Dispose()
```

This will cause the **DataSet** object to release its resources including he *XmlTextReader** object.